# D3 time format skips isoWeek

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datetime-format

When using d3.time.format(%Y%W) it doesn't give the expected output.

`d3.time.format("%Y%W").parse("201553")`
outputs
 `Mon Jan 04 2016`

Although the first Monday of week number 53 in 2015 is `Mon Dec 28 2015`

So it seems like it parses to the next week.

Any ideas how to fix this to get the expected output.

Comment: There's 52 weeks in a year so I'm guessing taking the next week is correct ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy It's not as simple as that. As in most cases when dealing with dates, this highly depends on the calendar in use. Have a look at wikipedia's article on *ISO week date*, particularly the section about the [*last week*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week). That said, one should expect to see a calendar week number 53 in 2015.

Comment: Okay then is there a way to fix it because I need to get the weeks between 2 dates. And I always get week 53 skipped.

Comment: @SalmaHamed Not using D3 built-ins, I'm afraid, since D3 doesn't seem to adhere to ISO 8601. See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568973/d3-time-format-skips-isoweek#comment62630510_37569474) below.

Comment: So would you suggest using momentjs for example for parsing date.

Comment: Yes, I just checked moment.js. Using `moment("201553", "YYYYWW").format("YYYY-MM-DD")` will evaluate to `2015-12-28` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The number of weeks is zero-based. `d3.time.format` defines a week number that is different from ISO 8601.

Check the documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

> %W - week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53].

It's the same for `%U`:

> %U - week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53].

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Week number `0` is used for all days preceding week no. 1, which in real life are actually part of week no. 52 or 53. Furthermore, 53 would make no sense, because there never will be a year having 54 weeks. @SalmaHamed

Comment: Check `d3.time.format("%W")(new Date())` returning `22` which is this week's one-based number. Unfortunately, this undermines your first assumption of D3's week numbers being zero-based. @SalmaHamed

Comment: @altocumulus: 2000 had 54 weeks.

Comment: 2000 actually had 52 weeks. Have a look at my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568973/d3-time-format-skips-isoweek#comment62627240_37568973) on the question itself: there is a maximum of 53 weeks which by definition will never be exceeded.

Comment: Hmm, according to Mike Bostock it's actually a feature, not a bug... There are *bug* reports on github, though, dealing with this: [*Week number unconsistency #2762*](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2762), [*Week of the year miscalculation? #2756*](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2756), [*time.format('%U') returns incorrect value #621*](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/621).

Comment: When you said that 2000 had 52 weeks I realised that you were talking about   iso8601.

Comment: Yes, the ISO week number scheme is what this question is all about.

Comment: Not for me. The question was about d3.time.format, and I believe my answer is correct. I'll edit it anyway, to make clear that it doesn't use ISO 8601.