# D3.js xAxis tickformat week number

Tags: datetime, d3.js, momentjs

The ISO week numbers are not right when trying to display them on the x-axis using tickformat.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%W").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
x.domain([parseDate("201552"), parseDate("201602")]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(d3.time.monday,1)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%W"))
```

This works fine with most of the scenario except with years that have 53 weeks.
Example: from week 201552 to week 201602. In this scenario it always skips week 53 so the the tick I get are [52, 01, 02]. although the expected output is [52,53,01,02]. [Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/rz0dm0pL/)

I also tried parsing the date string using momentjs since I face this problem [skip week in d3.time.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568973/d3-time-format-skips-isoweek)

This is the modified code using momentjs to parse the date:

```
var parseDate = function(d){
        return moment(d, "YYYYWW").toDate();
    }
x.domain([parseDate("201552"), parseDate("201602")]);
var MultiFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
      ["%W", function(d) {
          return moment(d).isoWeek();
      }],
    ]);
var xAxis_weeks = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.monday,1)
        .tickFormat( function(d) {return MultiFormat(d);})
```

Now the output is [51,52,01,02] which also should have been [52,53,01,02]

Comment: can u add a fiddle

Comment: I updated the question to include it (Y).

Comment: x.domain([parseDate("201552"), parseDate("201602")]); where does this 201552 and 201602 come from ?

Comment: it is string fetched from the url and passed as a string to the function.

Comment: parseDate("201552") prints Dec 28, so ther is no 53 th week in 2015, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z4124psr/1/

Comment: week number strts from index 0 itseems . parseDate("201500") prints Dec 29 2014, which is the first week of 2015

Comment: There seems like a problem in how d3 parses the date because year 2015 consisted of 53 weeks http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2015. And if the case is it starts from index zero, then should have done the same thing on year 2016 start. It should have stated week 00 first then week 01